# Variables in instance declaration

Tags: haskell

This snippet is from LYAH:

```
instance (Eq m) => Eq (Maybe m) where     

Just x == Just y = x == y      
Nothing == Nothing = True     
 _ == _ = False
```

I am totally confused as to what `x` and `y` are supposed to be since they are not defined anywhere. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, `==` is an *infix* function, you can read this as a pattern matching on:

```
(==) (Just x) (Just y)
```

In which case it is clear that `x` and `y` are the function parameters in the pattern matching.

A simpler example can be shown (without type classes) as:

```
areBothFive:: Int -> Int -> Bool
5 `areBothFive` 5 = True 
x `areBothFive` y = False -- the x and y are variables in the pattern match here

areBothFive 5 5 -- true
areBothFive 4 5 -- false
```

Here's [a fiddle illustrating the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7384558ae53c736e).

LYAH gives an example using this syntax in the "Syntax in Functions" chapter.

Answer (score 2):

They are there to [deconstruct the pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) `Just _` - so:

- `let (Just x) = Just 5` will give you `x <- 5`
- on the other hand `let (Just x) = Nothing` will just match (and fall through to another case - here it will be the `_ == _`

#### remark

the `let` is just there so that you can try this out in **GHCi**:

```
> let (Just x) = Just 5
> x
5

> let (Just x) = Nothing
> x
*** Exception: <interactive>:4:5-22: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (Just x)
```